# Python fold/reduce composition of multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce, fold

I want to achieve the following. It's essentially the composition or merging of an arbitrary number of dictionaries, with reference to a 'seed' or root dictionary, accumulating all unchanged and updated values in the final result.

```
seed = {
    'update': False,
    'data': {
        'subdata': {
            'field1': 5,
            'field2': '2018-01-30 00:00:00'
        },
        'field3': 2,
        'field4': None
    },
    'data_updates': {},
    'subdata_updates': {},
    'diffs': {}
}

update_1 = {
    'update': True,
    'data': {
        'subdata': {
            'field1': 6,
            'field2': '2018-01-30 00:00:00'
        },
        'field3': 2,
        'field4': None
    },
    'data_updates': {},
    'subdata_updates': {'field1': 6},
    'diffs': {
        'field1': {
            'field': 'field1',
            'before': 5,
            'after': 6
        }
    }
}

update_2 = {
    'update': True,
    'data': {
        'subdata': {
            'field1': 5,
            'field2': '2018-01-30 00:00:00',
        },
        'field3': 2,
        'field4': 1
    },
    'data_updates': {'field4': 1},
    'subdata_updates': {},
    'diffs': {
        'field4': {
            'field': 'field4',
            'before': None,
            'after': 1
        }
    }
}

# I want to be able to pass in an arbitrary number of updates.
assert reduce_maps(seed, *[update_1, update_2]) == {
    'update': True,
    'data': {
        'subdata': {
            'field1': 6,
            'field2': '2018-01-30 00:00:00',
        },
        'field3': 2,
        'field4': 1
    },
    'data_updates': {'field4': 1},
    'subdata_updates': {'field1': 6},
    'diffs': {
        'field1': {
            'field': 'field1',
            'before': 5,
            'after': 6
        },
        'field4': {
            'field': 'field4',
            'before': None,
            'after': 1
        }
    }
}
```

You can assume the data will always be in this shape, you can also assume that each payload only ever updates one field and that no two updates will ever update the same field.

I can dimly perceive an analogue of [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) lurking in the background here building up the data in passes around `seed`.

Comment: For problems this complex, it is perfectly fine to write your own solution. As the answer below illustrates, you can break the problem into smaller pieces and write a function for each piece. Once you have those working functions, you can then refactor them into more "elegant" structures, like replacing loops with list comprehensions.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, thanks. I am mainly interested to see what ideas come up that I might have missed.

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site [codereview.se]. After you write a working solution, the community there are more than happy to point out ways you can improve your code. This kind of review seems more in line with what you are trying to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import copy
from functools import partial, reduce

def traverse(seed, update, sentinel):
    for key, value in update.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            try:
                traverse(seed[key], update[key], sentinel)
            except KeyError:
                seed[key] = value
        else:
            if key not in seed or value != seed[key] \
                    and key not in sentinel:
                seed[key] = value
                sentinel.add(key)
    return seed


def reduce_maps(seed, *updates):
    seed = copy.deepcopy(seed)
    return reduce(
        partial(traverse, sentinel=set()), [seed, *updates]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
from pprint import pprint


def merge_working(pre, post):
    if not (isinstance(pre, dict) and isinstance(post, dict)):
        return post

    new = pre.copy()  # values for unique keys of pre will be preserved
    for key, post_value in post.items():
        new[key] = merge_working(new.get(key), post_value)

    return new


def merge_simplest(pre, post):
    if not isinstance(pre, dict):
        return post
    return {key: merge_simplest(pre[key], post[key])
            for key in pre}


merge = merge_working


def reduce_maps(*objects):
    new = objects[0]
    for post in objects[1:]:
        new = merge(new, post)
    return new


seed = {
    'update': False,
    'data': {
        'subdata': {
            'field1': 5,
            'field2': '2018-01-30 00:00:00'
        },
        'field3': 2,
        'field4': None
    },
    'data_updates': {},
    'subdata_updates': {},
    'diffs': {}
}

update_1 = {
    'update': True,
    'data': {
        'subdata': {
            'field1': 6,
            'field2': '2018-01-30 00:00:00'
        },
        'field3': 2,
        'field4': None
    },
    'data_updates': {},
    'subdata_updates': {'field1': 6},
    'diffs': {
        'field1': {
            'field': 'field 1',
            'before': 5,
            'after': 6
        }
    }
}

update_2 = {
    'update': True,
    'data': {
        'subdata': {
            'field1': 5,
            'field2': '2018-01-30 00:00:00',
        },
        'field3': 2,
        'field4': 1
    },
    'data_updates': {'field4': 1},
    'subdata_updates': {},  # was subdata_update
    'diffs': {
        'field4': {
            'field': 'field 4',
            'before': None,
            'after': 1
        }
    }
}

result = reduce_maps(*[seed, update_1, update_2])

golden = {
    'update': True,
    'data': {
        'subdata': {
            'field1': 5,  # was 6
            'field2': '2018-01-30 00:00:00',
        },
        'field3': 2,
        'field4': 1
    },
    'data_updates': {'field4': 1},
    'subdata_updates': {'field1': 6},  # was subdata_update
    'diffs': {
        'field1': {
            'field': 'field 1',
            'before': 5,
            'after': 6
        },
        'field4': {
            'field': 'field 4',
            'before': None,
            'after': 1
        }
    }
}

pprint(result)
pprint(golden)

assert result == golden
```

I've fixed what I think were typos in your data (see comments in the code).

Note that `merge` may need tweaking according to exact merging rules and possible data. To see what I mean, use `merge = merge_simplest` and understand why it fails. It wouldn't if the "data-agnostic" shape (understood as the dictionary tree disregarding values of leaves) were really the same.

Comment: Interesting thanks, looking into your solution. I'd quite *like* to avoid recursion if possible, but I will try and factor that out myself.

Comment: @jhrr Why would you like to avoid recursion?

Comment: It's just a style issue. I am perfectly happy using recursion but some devs aren't, so I'm just feeling out the 'solution-space' here, so to speak.

Comment: Actually as long as the recursion makes use of generators I think that'll be fine.